# Height in % = 0, if position is static or relative

Tags: css

I'm facing an issue whenever I set the `height` of `.task` in `%` then it's `height` becomes `0`. But at the same time if I will change `position` to `absolute` or `fixed`... it's working fine... why?

```css
* {
  font-family: monospace;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
section{
  margin-top: 8vh;
  min-height: 87vh;
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
}
section>.app{
  width: calc(100% - 22vh);
  min-height: inherit;
  background-color: inherit;
  left: 11vh;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 5vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
section>.app>input[type="search"]{
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 200%;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  height: 7vh;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 0.5vh solid white;
  color: deepskyblue;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-right: 0.25em;
  padding-left: 0.25em;
}
section>.app>input[type="search"]:valid{
  background-color: white;
  color: deepskyblue;
  border-bottom-color: deepskyblue;
}
section>.app>input[type="search"]::-webkit-input-placeholder{
  color: white;
}
section>.app>input[type="search"]::-moz-placeholder{
  color: white;
}
section>.app>input[type="search"]:-ms-input-placeholde {
  color: white;
}
section>.app>input[type="search"]::placeholde {
  color: white;
}
section>.app>input[type="search"]:focus{
  border-bottom-color: deepskyblue;
  background-color: inherit;
}
section>.app>input[type="search"]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder{
  color: transparent;
}
section>.app>input[type="search"]:focus::-moz-placeholder{
  color: transparent;
}
section>.app > input[type="search"]:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}
section>.app>input[type="search"]:focus::placeholder{
  color: transparent;
}
section>.app>div.tasks{
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5vh;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 70vh;
}
section>.app>div.tasks>.task {
  height: 10%;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="app">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search For Task List..." spellcheck="false" required="required"/>
    <div class="tasks">
      <div class="task"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I can't set the `position: absolute;` as `parent` element's `height` will no longer be `relative` to it's child.

You can also check out the full project here at codepen:

[Project at codepen](https://codepen.io/dhruvsinghal/pen/RZKwmR?editors=0100)

As the styling causing this problem, if removed will cause a problem in my project.... if so plz suggest an alternative.

Comment: I'm confused on your question.  The codepen looks fine, could you clear up what you are trying to ask?

Comment: see the `.task` just change `position:relative` to `position:absolute`

Comment: And you are just wondering why the `height` changes then?

Comment: no. i need the height in `position:relative`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are asking why it is that the `height = 0` when you explicitly initiated that property as `height: 10%;` for the `.task` class.  This is because the `position: relative;` property doesn't take elements out of the *flow* of things.  When you use `position: absolute;` for example, it does take that element out of the *flow* of things and it would then make it have a different height.

Comment: what should i do then.... i want a bunch `.task` and it's parent to adjust it's height relatively. i.e the browser window should scroll

Comment: Are you putting anything inside the '.task' or just using it to push the height of your page? @DhruvSinghal

Comment: i m going to put different task list boxes and in that there will be a list of tasks... btw i faced the same problem with it's parent element..... i.e. one with black background. bu i calculated the minimum height it should get in vh and therefore resulted in `min-height:70vh`... what can i do for this?

Comment: Im not on a computer anymore but i think when you add lists to that 'div' it should change the height once elements are inside it. Hope i was able to help a bit @DhruvSinghal

Comment: you helped a lot..... thanks.... but with that i m not able to set a minimum height to that div